# A PowerPoint add-in module in VBA that searches for textboxes with numbers and text then repositions them to overlay the bottom-left of an image

Tags: vba, powerpoint, powerpoint-addins

Objective of the code:

Create a PowerPoint add-in module in VBA that searches for textboxes that have the shape-fill hex code #002466 where the first character is a number and the second character is a period.
Then, search the same slide for images with a height that is over 11cm and a width that is over 22cm.
Then reposition the textboxes that meet the above criteria so that their bottom-left corner aligns with the bottom-left corner of the image that meets the image criteria.

Extra Information:

The PowerPoint project has a width of 33.867 cm and a height of 19.05 cm.
All slides are in landscape orientation and positions are measured in cm, not points.
All security settings for macros are enabled and other subs have been run in the same PPT.

Problem:
I run the code and nothing happens. No errors but no movement either.

Attempts so far:
I run the following code and nothing happens; no errors but also no repositioning. I've also tried converting the cm into points and that hasn't worked.

There are text boxes that I'm using to caption screenshots and I've made code to recolor these that worked. Here is that code:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub ChangeShapeFill()
    Dim sld As Slide
    Dim shp As Shape
    Dim count As Integer
    count = 0
    For Each sld In ActivePresentation.Slides
        For Each shp In sld.Shapes
            If shp.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(20, 108, 253) Then
                shp.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 36, 102)
                shp.Line.Weight = 1
                shp.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 255)
                count = count + 1
            End If
        Next shp
    Next sld
    MsgBox "Updated " & count & " shapes.", vbOKOnly, "Shape Fill Update"
    Beep
End Sub
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
Sub RepositionTextBoxes()

    ' Set variables for image size criteria
    Const minWidth As Double = 22 ' cm
    Const minHeight As Double = 11 ' cm
    
    ' Set variables for slide size
    Const slideWidth As Double = 33.867 ' cm
    Const slideHeight As Double = 19.05 ' cm
    
    ' Set variables for textbox fill color criteria
    Const hexCode As String = "#002466"
    
    Dim sld As Slide
    Dim shp As Shape
    Dim img As Shape
    Dim txt As Shape
    
    ' Loop through each slide in the presentation
    For Each sld In ActivePresentation.Slides
        
        ' Loop through each shape on the slide
        For Each shp In sld.Shapes
            
            ' Check if shape is a textbox and has the correct fill color
            If shp.Type = msoTextBox And shp.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 36, 102) And _
               IsNumeric(Mid(shp.Fill.ForeColor.RGB, 2, 1)) And _
               Mid(shp.Fill.ForeColor.RGB, 3, 1) = "." Then
                
                ' Loop through each image on the slide
                For Each img In sld.Shapes
                    If img.Type = msoPicture And img.Height / 28.3465 > minHeight And _
                       img.Width / 28.3465 > minWidth Then ' convert height and width to cm
                        
                        ' Reposition the textbox to align with the bottom-left corner of the image
                        Set txt = shp.Duplicate
                        txt.Left = img.Left
                        txt.Top = slideHeight - img.Top - img.Height
                        txt.Height = shp.Height
                        txt.Width = shp.Width
                        
                        ' Delete the original textbox
                        shp.Delete
                        
                        ' Exit the loop through images
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next img
                
            End If
            
        Next shp
        
    Next sld

End Sub
```

Comment: While your preferred measurement units may be metric, you want to use POINTS in VBA.

Answer (score 0):

First you have a loop through the shapes, looking for a textbox:

```
For Each shp In sld.Shapes
```

But then inside that you have another loop through shapes, looking for a picture:

```
For Each img In sld.Shapes
```

One loop at a time please!

Your question needs to be tightened up so you are asking just one thing about one piece of code. Your current listing requires a lot of setup just to test. Please pare it down to just the code causing the problem. Here's some good reading: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I'm quite new to coding and self-taught. Thank you for the links to creating better examples.